# Which filters should i use to edge dedection a picture?

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to use filters, image processing to get edges of an object by using Python. My image and targeted images are here: [Original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOvE7.jpg) [Targeted image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCLfh.jpg)

Since colors are close to each other i'm having hard time to sepereate dolphins from background.

I've tried some filters such as median filter and tried some morhpological operators.

Comment: This is not trivial. Trivial local filters will never do this. You need more global understanding: is it a shadow? Is it a dolphin? Is it a wave? Then you can filter out edges of only the features you’re interested in.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your answer, what do you mean? To be clear i only want the dolphins to be highlighted. I know target picture highlighted other things such as dolphins' shadows and waves too but i don't want that.

Comment: You are using local filters. Local filters can’t tell the difference between a dolphin and a wave and a rock. They just see if a pixel is on an edge of something or not. To do what you want, you need more complex things than just local filters.

Comment: Such as what? Can you give me some examples?

Comment: By the way if you're talking about ai or something lik that, that's my homework and im limited only to use filters and some basic algorithms and no ai.